# ' TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not list' Python

Tags: python, list, date

I'm getting this error

```py
raise TypeError('Parser must be a string or character stream, not '
TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not list
```

My code:

```
for page in range(1, int(no_pages)):
    req = requests.get(url3 + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    time = soup.find_all('time', {"class":"timeago b-card--el-agency-time"})
    m_time = [item['datetime'] for item in time]
    unf_time = dateutil.parser.parse(m_time)
    r_time = unf_time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%S')
    l7 = r_time
    s7 = pd.Series(l7, name='Time Posted')
    df = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3,s7,s4,s6+s5], axis=1)
```

As its in a **for loop**, its taking the data as a **list**.
How do I prevent this **error**?
I want the output like this:

```
    Time
0 08-25-2020:09:44:06
1 08-22-2020:09:44:06
2 08-29-2020:09:44:06
3 08-21-2020:09:44:06
etc.
```

So how do I do it?

Comment: you are passing a list inside `dateutil.parser.parse` but it only accepts an string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing array here `unf_time = dateutil.parser.parse(m_time)` where it expects a single string

you can write it to handle array as

```
r_time = [dateutil.parser.parse(item['datetime']).strftime('%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%S') for item in time]
```

and rest of code continuous

```
s7 = pd.Series(r_time, name='Time Posted')
df = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3,s7,s4,s6+s5], axis=1)
```

Comment: I'll check it out!

Comment: Sure, feel free to upvote and accept as answer if it helped

Comment: Will do! (30 chars)

Comment: Works! my friend.